# Why does rounding -0.1 return -0

Tags: javascript

While testing, I noticed something strange with [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round).

When I was rounding negative numbers close to `0` (`-0.1`, `-0.01`, etc), the return value in my console would be `-0` rather than `0`. Even stranger, if I were to set that same value to an element's text, the element would display `0`, instead of `-0`.

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/qcug9/

[image]

Can anyone explain why this occurs? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Also, I am using ***Chrome Version 33.0.1750.117***.

Comment: `-0 == 0` evaluates to true

Comment: Is the actual question "What is -0 and why is it different to 0?"

Comment: This is a quirk of Javascript.  Read http://www.2ality.com/2013/04/quirk-undefined.html for more info.  Also search: Javascript Quirks for some other fun.

Comment: -0.1 is closer to -0 than to 0...

Comment: @Gareth if it considered `0 !== 0` then I would say your question is more fitting. But since it is equal, I am more curious as to why it occurs in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kind of numbers JavaScript uses (IEEE-754 double-precision floating point) have the concept of both "positive" and "negative" zero.

The next highest integer to `-0.1` is `-0`. "Highest" in this case means "toward positive infinity."

From [the specification, §15.8.2.15 *"Math.round"*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.2.15):

> If `x` is less than `0` but greater than or equal to `-0.5`, the result is `−0`.

`-0` and `+0` are both *rendered* as just `0` when converted to string. For instance:

```
console.log(-0)         // 0 or -0 depending on what console you use
console.log(String(-0)) // 0 (always)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, TJ! I found something very interesting in the article you provided.  `Note that there is both a positive zero and a negative zero. For brevity, these values are also referred to for expository purposes by the symbols +0 and −0, respectively. (Note that these two different zero Number values are produced by the program expressions +0 (or simply 0) and -0.)`

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript uses [IEEE-754 to represent numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Formats) and that spec considers `0` and `-0` to be technically different.  Presumably, negative zero is the integer nearest to those values, as defined by [`Math.round(x)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round).

Note that zero is both loosely and strictly equal to negative zero (`0==-0` and `0===-0`).

You can workaround by doing `Math.abs(Math.round(x))` if you don't want to see `-0`.

Comment: I am not sure why you were downvoted, I thought your answer was informative! Thanks again for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 1):

The IEEE double precision format allows for negative zero (distinct from positive 0). The values are considered almost equal (e.g. they're equal even if you compare with `===` and `-0` is not considered "less than" `0`) but for example `1/0` is `infinity` while `1/-0` is `-infinity`.

IMO You shouldn't try to read too much into this semantic.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer! I also noticed `0 === -0` and I will definitely take your advice for not reading too much into this. :-D